# Required Bash Code for Hide Password during Typing

Tags: linux, bash, password

How can I write Bash Code for Hiding Password Or convert into '*'
user input will be in string so no spaces, and change or hide password String.

Comment: A string is a string even if it contains spaces, and passwords often contain spaces...

Comment: Oooph, tough call for me on VTC here. The target Q does have *an* answer that would print asterisks, as asked ([in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/487164/required-bash-code-for-hide-password-during-typing#comment893666_487166)) in this question, but it doesn't handle [backspaces](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/487164/required-bash-code-for-hide-password-during-typing#comment893864_487166) as also hinted at here. I'll VTC because it's a good duplicate otherwise, but if this question is edited to incorporate new requirements, it *could* become separate.

Answer (score 13):

Use `read -s` to not echo the input, i.e. show nothing when the user types the password:

```
read -p 'Password? ' -s password
echo Your password is "$password".
```

Comment: instead of hiding can i convert to character *

Comment: Not so easily. You can `read -n1` and display the asterisk yourself, though.

Comment: @choroba: I've just tested a bit, and -- it looks like using `read -n1` for this has some sharply negative consequences, e.g. in that it's a lot of work to try to support backspace.

Comment: @AlphaCoder It is not idiomatic in Unix to display even the length of a password at the CLI.

Comment: @ruakh: Yes, that's part of the "not so easily".

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `systemd-ask-password`, the password will displayed as asterisks while typing.

Format: (`systemd-ask-password --help`)

```
systemd-ask-password [OPTIONS...] MESSAGE
```

e,g:

```
PASSWORD=$(systemd-ask-password "Please type your Password:")
Please type your Password: ***********
```

Comment: When I try this, I get `bash: systemd-ask-password: command not found` . . .

Comment: @ruakh `systemd-ask-password` is a part of systemd.